# Headphone jack stops web browser playback

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

I have a headphone jack acting as the main speakers (because I have a set up without speakers).

It's a Windows 10 system with 3.5mm Sennheiser HD25 at the front of the PC. The problem occurs when for example, I play a YouTube music video. If I nudge it, the headphone jack disconnects. When I reconnect it, the YouTube video does not recognize that the headphones have been reconnected, but the system does. It is so annoying if I am gaming for example. I have to alt+tab and replay the video (if I am through a two hour music set, forget about returning to the same point). Grrrr!

Is there a fix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same behavior with a different audio cable or headphones? Fan you borrow a USB speaker or headphones and does the problem persist when those are used.

Most systems these days will automatically pause media when the audio device disconnects. Based on your description I would guess you have a bad audio cable, or a loose or failing connection inside the laptop at the audio jack.

You can isolate and confirm this using a different audio cable, or a USB audio output device.

If another analog audio cable works ok, the problem was your old cable.

If another analog audio cable has the same problem the issue is inside your computer and is probably a hardware fault.

Getting a USB audio device would be the cheapest fix in this case, especially if the laptop is no longer under warranty.